# How to improve the Matrix's rain javascript code performance

Tags: javascript, performance, matrix

i am a new programmer, i want to make something cool,such as Matrix rain.I know use canvas it's better,but i want to know how to max the performance the native javascript version.

JSFiddle version is here [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdkai1989/6mmdrkbp/4/)!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Matrix</title>
    <style>
        html, body {margin:0; padding:0; background-color:#000;}
        #matrix {margin: 0px auto; overflow:hidden; position: relative;}
        .divText {position: absolute;}
        .divText span {display:block; margin:1px; font-family:sans-serif; }
    </style>
    <script src="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="spanCount">0</span>
<div id="matrix">

</div>
<script>
    function rand(min, max)
    {
        return min + Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min));
    }
    var htmllist=[];
    (function init(){
        var width=$(window).width(),
                height=$(window).height();
        $('#matrix').height(height).width(width);
        var dataSource=['凵', '凵','夂','彡','厶','工','匸','匚','乀','乁','彐','丩','忄','卄','凵','孒','讠','巜','彑','攵' ];
        var lengthOfAarry=dataSource.length;

        var color = [];
        for (var i=1; i<17; i++)
        {
            var f = i.toString(16);
            color.push('0' + f + '0');
        }
        for(var j=0;j<100;j++){

            var fontSize =rand(10,30);
            var html = '<div class="divText" style="left:' + rand(0,width) + 'px; bottom:'+height+'px;">';
            c="";
            for (var i=1; i<17; i++)
            {
                c =c+ Math.round(Math.random()).toString();
                html+='<span class="s' + i + '" style="color:#' + color[i-1] + '; font-size:' + fontSize + 'px; text-shadow:0px 0px 10px #' + color[i-1] + ';">' + c + '</span>';
            }

            html+='</div>';
            htmllist.push(html);
        }

    })();
    function add(){
        $('#matrix').append(htmllist[rand(0,100)]);
    }

    (function run()
    {

        add();

        $('.divText').each(function(){
            var y = $(this).css('bottom');
            y = parseInt(y)-15;
            $(this).css('bottom', '' + y + 'px');
            if (y + $(this).height() <= 0)
            {
                $(this).remove();
                return;
            }
            $(this).find('span').each(function(){
                var c = Math.round(Math.random()).toString();
                $(this).html(c);
            });
        });

        setTimeout(run, 50);
    })();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So after run this code in browsers It will show like this 
Thanks all the guy's

Comment: That's the jsfiddle link [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdkai1989/6mmdrkbp/4/)

Comment: In terms of performance, what do you intend to improve specifically? Maximizing the number of particles at a time? The Maximum speed of the free-falling particles?

Comment: I want make a Matrix rain not showing so slow,  and want to know have i reach the max ability of DOM. Or if use canvas it's the only way to make it better.@TaoP.R.

Comment: Canvas just basically helps you draw the graphic more comfortably or more appropriately. WebGL would be the optimal choice for graphic render improvement because it allows you to gain power of GPU.

Comment: Cool，maybe i can make different versions. Like Print Hello world in 100 ways. So fun